# How do I use Pyserial to detect if a serial port is being used by another application?

Tags: python, pyserial

In general, how do I use `Pyserial` to detect if a serial port is being used by another application?

**Case in point:** 
If my serial device `/dev/ttyUSB0` is presently accessed by an application. E.g.  `picocom /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200` is running (but it can be other applications). Next I use Pyserial to access the same serial port. I am expecting `serial.Serial.read()` to throw out a `SerialException` expecption according to the [read](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/serialposix.py#L523) method. However this did not happen.

Below is my test script and its result showing `read_data =  b''` but the `SerialException` was not triggered.

**Script:**

```
import serial
from pprint import pprint

port='/dev/ttyUSB0'
try:
    serial_port = serial.Serial(port=port, baudrate=115200, timeout=5 )
    read_data = serial_port.read()
#except serial.serialutil.SerialException as e:
except serial.SerialException as e:
    print(e)
else:
    print('serial_port:'); pprint(serial_port.__dict__)
    print('\nread_data = ', read_data)
    if not read_data:
        print("read_data == zero or empty container or False")

serial_port.close()
```

**Output:**

```
serial_port:
{'_baudrate': 115200,
 '_break_state': False,
 '_bytesize': 8,
 '_dsrdtr': False,
 '_dtr_state': True,
 '_exclusive': None,
 '_inter_byte_timeout': None,
 '_parity': 'N',
 '_port': '/dev/ttyUSB0',
 '_rs485_mode': None,
 '_rts_state': True,
 '_rtscts': False,
 '_stopbits': 1,
 '_timeout': 5,
 '_write_timeout': None,
 '_xonxoff': False,
 'fd': 6,
 'is_open': True,
 'name': '/dev/ttyUSB0',
 'pipe_abort_read_r': 7,
 'pipe_abort_read_w': 8,
 'pipe_abort_write_r': 9,
 'pipe_abort_write_w': 10,
 'portstr': '/dev/ttyUSB0'}

read_data =  b''
read_data == zero or empty container or False
```